# How to manipulate multiple file names using find?

Tags: bash, find, rename, csh

How to improve the command below to change a string in a filename.

```
find . -type f -name '*<today>*' -exec mv {} {}_renamed \;
```

Actually I have a few files in my directory with today's date as a part of the name.
I want to change the names of all the files such that only the date string in the file name will be changed to yesterday's date from today's date.

I do not want to put a suffix or prefix to file name instead manipulate the file name.

e.g.
before command file name is `xxx20170821yyyy.ppp`
after command file name will be `xxx20170820yyyy.ppp`

and repeat this for all the files which has `20170821` string in theirname.

Comment: Have a look at `rename`. You don't even need find then (unless your files are spread over nested directories. If you don't succeed with `rename` tell us what you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rename` as part of Perl commands.

```
find . -type f -name '*20170919*' -execdir 
rename -n 's/20170919/20170918/' '{}' \;
```

Use `execdir` as it's performing its part command to be run for file found in their relative path where `execdir` returns. This swill prevent passing full path of file (relative to current working directory) and avoid a folder with same *pattern* to be renaming wrong instead of file name itself.

If all your files are in single directory, below one liner `rename` is enough.

```
rename -n 's/20170919/20170918/' *20170919*
```

Remove `-n` when you trust the rename result to have actual rename. You may need to add `-v` to see what being renaming.

At the end, you may need to have today's date if you want this perform everyday for bunch of files. then use `date` command as following in `$(...)` (command substitution) between double quotes.

```
find . -type f -name "*$(date +"%Y%m%d")*" -execdir 
rename -n "s/$(date +"%Y%m%d")/$(date -d "-1day" +"%Y%m%d")/" '{}' \;
```

P.s, since you are using `csh` shell, you need to use `` `...` `` instead of `$(...)`, or better switch to new shells like `bash`, `zsh`.

```
find ./ -type f -name "*`date +"%Y%m%d"`*" -execdir 
rename -n "s/`date +"%Y%m%d"`/`date -d "-1day" +"%Y%m%d"`/" '{}' \;
```

Comment: I don't know what `rename` does to paths, but it does get the full path to the file, not just the basename. Will it rename path components?

Comment: @Kusalananda correct, we can use `execdir` instead of `-exec`, I did change

Comment: CMD:`'$ find . -type f -name '*$(date +"%Y%m%d")*' -execdir rename -n 's/$(date +"%Y%m%d" ) /$(date -d "-1day" +"%Y%m%d" ) /' '{}' +`
                                                                                                         
                   Getting below Error:
find: The current directory is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove the current directory from your $PATH (that is, remove "." or leading or trailing colons)

Comment: @BreakBadSP for that please refer to this post [Why using the '-execdir' action is insecure for directory which is in the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621132/why-using-the-execdir-action-is-insecure-for-directory-which-is-in-the-path)